# Nodejs or ExpressJS Windows Authentication

Tags: node.js, express, windows-authentication

I would like to authenticate a windows user in `NodeJS` app.
Is there any add-on for this yet ? There is [`node-krb5`](https://github.com/qesuto/node-krb5) but it doesn't support windows yet.

Answer (score 6):

If you host on IIS with iisnode https://github.com/auth0/passport-windowsauth works nicely! passport-windowsauth comes with an ad integration but if you only want the username in order to implement your own authorzation logic you can do it like this

web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <iisnode promoteServerVars="LOGON_USER" />
</system.webServer>
```

server.js:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var WindowsStrategy = require('passport-windowsauth');

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.use(new WindowsStrategy({
    integrated: true 
}, function(profile,done) {
    var user = {
        id: profile.id,
    };
    done(null, user);
}));

app.all("*", passport.authenticate("WindowsAuthentication"), function (request,response,next){
    next();
});
```

then you can access the userid on the request object in your other routes:

```
app.get("/api/testAuthentication", function(request, response){
    console.log(request.user.id + " is authenticated");
});
```

if you want to implement your own authorization logic using the user id you can define a middleware function like this:

```
app.get("/api/testAuthorization", hasRole("a role"), function(request, response, next){
    console.log(request.user.id " is authenticated and authorized");
});
```

where hasRole looks like this:

```
function hasRole(role) {
    return function(request,response,next){
        //your own authorzation logic

        if(role == "a role")
            next();
        else
            response.status(403).send();
    }
}
```

Comment: But when we put node behind IIS, we loose lots of Node benefits!

Comment: I am able to get the response `( request.user.id )` from Url in the browser. but when I am trying to access the same URL, I am getting error Unauthorized error. I know this post is old but if possible, Can you share any example where you have used this kind of thing?

Comment: can I use passport-windowsauth without IISNode

Comment: I don't understand what passport windows-auth is adding here: already `iisnode` has `promoteServerVars` and that's enough to run node under IIS and to get the logon user when the windows auth is negotiated.

Answer (score 1):

`node-sspi`: found it easy and efficient to use.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sspi

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am the author of node-expose-sspi.

https://github.com/jlguenego/node-expose-sspi

is dedicated to do SSO on Windows using Kerberos or NTLM.
It uses Negotiate and SPNEGO token.

Comment: Tried it out but it is working only from a localhost url, not from a real domain intranet... In the latter case the browser (chrome, edge) keeps asking user/password without a succesful connection. Tested on the trivial localhost it does work, but how is that useful?

Comment: in NTLM yes, but if you use a domain and Kerberos then no popup will appear.

Comment: Is it something easily doable only at application level in node.js (how?) or what else does it imply? If you prefer, we can follow up on [github](https://github.com/jlguenego/node-expose-sspi/issues/19). Thank you anyway for your reply!

Comment: With Kerberos, your windows account must run on a MS Windows domain server. And the navigator must trust the website url. This is only doable for an intranet application. node-expose-sspi is designed only for this situation. For internet connection authentication, you should use for instance OAuth2.

Comment: Yes, I'm on a *intranet* connection authentication, with domain servers etc.. I don't understand why the authentication is not passed... (btw, if you have time, do you prefer to discuss here or on the github?). Just to say, iisnode is working